# Symfony form submits wrong data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In Symfony I have this part of my code where I am building a view with some data and a form with some radio buttons. When submitting the form I am doing a dump in the view to check which data has been submitted, but the data does not match with the one the form was build. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
public function playAction(Request $request){
    $data = $this->getDbQuestion();
    $questionData = $data[0];
    dump($questionData);
    $answerData = $data[1];
    dump($answerData);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($answerData)
    ->add('answers', ChoiceType::class,
         array(
             'choices'=>  $answerData,
             'multiple'=>false,'expanded'=>true,
             'choice_label' => 'answer',
    ))
    ->add('Submit',SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send Answer'))
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted()) {
         $formData = $form->getData();
         return $this->render('QuizViews/correctAnswer.html.twig', array(
                'ss' => $formData
        ));
    }
    return $this->render('QuizViews/playQuiz.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'question' => $questionData
    ));
}
```

> Twig

```
<a href="/quiz/question">
    <input type="button" value="Start Quiz" />
</a>
<br>
FormData Correct {{ dump(ss) }}
```

[image: Form data]

[image: Submitted form Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting, this might be a better solution for the answer section:

```
->add('answers', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Answer',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->where('a.question_id->getId() = :qID')
                ->setParameter('qID', 1);
    },
     'multiple'=>false,
     'expanded'=>true,
    'choice_label' => 'answer',
))
```

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Your call to get the data after verifying the form isSubmitted is incorrect. You need to call like so:

```
$formData = $form->get('answers')->getData();
```

That just gets the 'answers' only.

Edit #2
You might also want to change this:

```
->add('answers', ChoiceType::class,
    array(
        'choices'=>  $answerData,
        'multiple'=>false,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'choice_label' => 'answer',
        'choice_value' => $answerData,
))
```

Which sets the 'choice_value', what is actually selected and returned from the getData().

Can you post your twig answers file please? Edit your post and so I can see.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is like in my second screenshot "answers" => Answer. But the data is still incorrect.

Comment: Is the answer you are seeing is "rasp11,rasp22,rasp33,rasp44", but you are expecting "rasp111,rasp222,rasp333,rasp444"?

Comment: yes something like that. Like in the screenshots above when I select "rasp22" I get in my view "rasp222" or "rasp2" or "rasp2222". This are all the answers for other questions.

Comment: Actually, how do you create `$data[1]`? Or how to create `$data`? Can you show me the code? Looks like that is where the problem is.

Comment: Also for example if for a question I select 'rasp1' then the wrong answers will always be rasp11, or rasp111, or rasp1111. Never rasp2, rasp22, rasp333 etc.

Comment: I know this is not the best approach, but here is the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fUnp7km_-MUobNL3o1Wh86D1MY0u2vFy4FWMViILvso/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have also chages the ->add but now I get an error: The option "choice_value" with value array is expected to be of type "null" or "callable" or "string" or "Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyPath", but is of type "array".

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong advice. That should have been for an 'EntityType::class'. Have you considered to redesign your code? You can make your 'Answers' an Entity, then your form can refer to an Entity. You can have an Entity 'Question', and a 'Answers' Entity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115666/discussion-between-otonel-and-alvin-bunk).

Comment: I do have an entity "Answer"

Comment: The correct data is submitted, the only problem is that this is not consistent as sometimes the data submitted is NULL.